# Using CoreData to save and retrieve data from TextFields

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sqlite, core-data

**Program Info**

Hi! First question i've posted on Stackoverflow, so here it goes:
I am currently writing a program for used part inspection and need to be able to       save the customer info using Core Data (or something else, if it is recommended). I just need to save it and then retrieve it to make a PDF.

**Issues**

-I am getting an error upon hitting the save button that says : 
   -I have no clue how to retrieve the data and convert it to PDF ( but thats a separate issue entirely)

---

---

**Error**

```
*2016-06-17 11:15:54.336 NewParts[6803:2846480] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1AAF2587-19C6-424F-BA3A-F37BBEE4AC71/Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The managed object model version used to open the persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the persistent store." UserInfo={metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 641;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "F4F8EB7F-B2EB-4D7F-A2A3-45FA91F8582E";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
},*
```

**Save Button Action**

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    var entity1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("UsedInfo", inManagedObjectContext:context) as NSManagedObject
    entity1.setValue("Test", forKey: "product")

    do {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }


}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that i am a total iOS/Swift noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error that you've post actually have an explanation

> Code=134100  The managed object model version used to open the
>   persistent store is incompatible with the one that was used to create
>   the persistent store

If your app is not published on the AppStore, you can simply remove app from the device (or simulator), Clean project and do Build&Run.

Whenever you make changes to Core Data definition you should delete the app and rebuild.

If your app is on AppStore, you should perform Core Data migration, you can find a lot of information on the Internet.

Apple [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html), explains how to perform Automatic Lightweight Migration :

> You request automatic lightweight migration using the options
>   dictionary you pass in
>   addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:, by
>   setting values corresponding to both the
>   NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption and the
>   NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption keys to YES:

Which means that you can pass following options to your persistent coordinator :

```
let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]

coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType,configuration: nil,URL : storeURL, options as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: Thank you! Uninstalling the application and cleaning the build removed the error. I just have one last question, if you could answer it so that i could have some clarity. When i print off the value i entered for the textfield "product", i get the test value Optional(Test), which is technically correct, because i set the value to "Test". Any idea what the Optional() part is? I just want to make sure it is adding everything correctly.

Comment: You are welcome, regarding the Optional - if you look at UITextfield's property text :    public var text: String? // default is nil. You can see that it's optional String. So when you see Optional(Test) it just means that the value is type of String? (optional string) and contains value "Test".

Comment: Swift introduces optional types, which handle the absence of a value. Optionals say either “there is a value, and it equals x” or “there isn’t a value at all” You can read more : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: Thank you! You've been very helpful!